# How to update the average rating for an Instructor using aggregate in mongoose (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

This is my instructor schema

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema;
const instructorSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  userName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  rating:[{
    type: Number
}],
  biography: {
    type: String,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
  },
  education: {
    type: String,
  },
  projects: {
    type: String,
  },
  reviews: {
    type: String,
  },
});
const Instructor = mongoose.model("Instructor", instructorSchema);
module.exports = Instructor;
```

**As you can see the rating is an attribute as an array.**

This is the get method I tried in the controller file of the instructor.

```
const viewRating=async(req,res,next)=>{
   Instructor.aggregate([
      { $match: { "instructor" : req.params.id } },
      { $unwind: "$rating" },
      { $group : {_id : "$_id", avgRate : {  $avg : "$rating.rate" } } }
  ], function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return;
      }
      console.log(result);
  });

}
```

This is what I type to try in postman

http://localhost:2000/instructor/viewRating/635fc912173f6eba9de32337

It keeps loading endlessly.

**my router file(only what's relevant to the problem)**

```
instRouter.get("/viewRating/:id",viewRating)
```

**my index.js(only what's relevant to the problem)**

```
app.use("/instructor",instRouter);
```

I believe the problem is in the get method but I don't know how to use the aggregate correctly.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is really inefficient... or well, should be. Because you are filtering by `instructor` but I can't see that property on the schema, so the query should return null.

But also the problem is the way you are trying to do the average. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something and the `$match` get the entire collection and then the `$unwind` is really really slow

At this point you are deconstructing the whole array to reconstruct again calculating the acerage.

I think you can combine `$project` and `$avg` which output the average of the array without extra steps:

```
{
  "$project": {
    "rating": {
      "$avg": "$rating"
    }
  }
}
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9jSJkZMDP6I)

So your query should be something like this:

```js
Instructor.aggregate([
      { $match: { "instructor" : req.params.id } }, // your match here, maybe you have to modify
      { $project: { "rating": { "$avg": "$rating" } }
}
  ], function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return;
      }
      console.log(result);
  });
```